# Any way to disable Ctrl+L keyboard shortcut for clearing scrollback in Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin

I am using Pidgin 2.7.1 on Windows XP and I noticed that if I am in a conversation window and I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, it clears my conversation history and there is no easy way of getting it back (as far as I know). I think this keyboard shortcut is very annoying. I never do this on purpose. It usually happens if I think I am in Firefox and try to focus the address bar by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, but instead end up clearing my Pidgin scrollback.

I have no use for such a quick and easy way of triggering a feature that I will rarely, if ever, have any reason to use. Is there any way of disabling the keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GTK 2 applications support "live" changing of menu keyboard accelerators.

1. Add this line to your `~/.gtkrc-2.0` (on Windows - `%USERPROFILE%\.gtkrc-2.0`):

   ```
   gtk-can-change-accels = 1
   ```

   Edit: **YES YOU NEED TO CREATE THAT FILE IF IT DOES NOT EXIST.**

   Edit 2: **Do not modify the one in Pidgin's directory.**
2. Restart Pidgin.
3. Open an IM window.
4. Open the *Conversation* menu and **select** *Clear scrollback*: move the cursor over it but **do not click**.
5. Press the new shortcut. (<kbd>Delete</kbd> should erase the shortcut completely.)
6. Close the menu.

The changes will be live immediately.

Accelerators are stored as a plain text file in the program's settings directory; on Windows, that would be `%APPDATA%\.purple\accels`.

---

- *Using Pidgin*: [How do I bind keystrokes to menu items?](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#HowdoIbindkeystrokestomenuitems)

Comment: It's here in the 2.7.1+ release: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\Gtk\etc\gtk-2.0` (of course if you havent got 64bit OS, then Program files simply.)

Comment: @Shiki: That one *is* Pidgin's own `gtkrc`, yes, but I prefer editing the one in my user directory, so that I would get consistent behavior among all GTK programs, and that my changes would not affect other users. (The latter is the most annoying thing ever. It's not 1998 anymore... `#include <rants/windows-lua-bugs.h>`)

Comment: Okay okay I know what you mean but pidgin doesnt use this config method since 2.7.x. At least not here. It was OK until 2.7.x. | (Maybe it works if you put it here, but dunno why it wont create a file like it did. Still, your answer worth my +1. :))

Comment: @Shiki: If you're talking about `~/.gtkrc-2.0` -- **all** GTK2 programs use it. Some have their own, but all read the global configuration. (FWIW, Pidgin also reads `~/.purple/gtkrc-2.0`.)

Comment: @Shiki: Also, re "Maybe it works if you put it here, but dunno why it wont create a file like it did.": Why _should_ it? `~/.gtkrc-2.0` is in the user's territory, not the program's. It is also a global configuration file, not Pidgin-specific. Thus Pidgin will not and should not create it. It stays inside its own area (`~/.purple/`).

Comment: Oh well, I don't really want to change anything, its fine as it is, and ctrl+L is a very handy, very good hotkey in pidgin (I always manage to avoid this clearing stuff, but even if I do a mistake, log is there (for a few min/hours) to help me out >.> .. (Thanks for the explanation, saved, I'll mess around gtk anyway, ty.)

Comment: I don't see any %USERPROFILE%\.gtkrc-2.0 file. I tried just %USERPROFILE% and it took me to my Documents and Settings folder but I don't see any .gtkrc-2.0 file within it. Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: I tried Shiki's suggestion of looking for the gtkrc file in C:\Program Files\Pidgin\Gtk\etc\gtk-2.0. I modified it like grawity described, then went through the rest of the procedure. It worked.

Comment: @mikez302: You need to **create** that file yourself. You **should not** modify the system one.

Comment: Will anything bad happen if I modify the file in the Pidgin directory? I did that, then deleted the shortcut, then changed it back. Everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: @mikez302: It will not damage anything, no. It's just not the right way. Your own settings should stay inside your own directories (`%USERPROFILE%`), because:

1) Editing the file in `Pidgin\Gtk\etc` requires administrator privileges by default. Editing your own doesn't.

2) Editing `Pidgin\Gtk\etc` will affect other users, who may not want the changes. (I'm a Linux user, so I always consider this.)

3) All files in `Pidgin\Gtk\etc` will get overwritten whenever you upgrade Pidgin. On the other hand, the one in `%USERPROFILE%` will remain untouched: it belongs to you.

Answer (score 0):

Found on [flynsarmy.com](http://www.flynsarmy.com/2012/10/how-to-remove-ctrll-key-binding-from-pidgin/).

Open `~/.purple/accels` under Linux, `%APPDATA%\.purple\accels` under Windows

Add at the end
`(gtk_accel_path "<main>/Conversation/Clear Scrollback" "")`

Maybe be sure not another line containing `Conversation/Clear` is there.
(Lines starting with a semicolon `;` are comments and don't count.)

You may need to restart Pidgin.

Answer (score -1):

`ALT+C` + `L` brings up the log instantly if I ever need it.

About the key... maybe you can modify the source, remove the shortcut and recompile it, make a binary.
(I only know a person who does such binaries. Maybe I'll also build up a build environment.)